# правильная сортировка массива по значению

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

есть массив

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM1
                [id] => 1
                [voites] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM2
                [id] => 2
                [voites] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM3
                [id] => 3
                [voites] => 4 // высший рейтинг
            )
         [3] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM4
                [id] => 4
                [voites] => 0
            )
```

нужно отсортировать по полю `voites`... и нужно, чтобы не нарушался порядок..
например, обычная отсортировка выводит сначала элемент с наибольшим значение в `voites`(что и логично), но остальные, у которых это поле равно `0`, выводит с конца... сортирую через `usort()`... не получается написать к нему `cmp функцию`

```
public function srtCMP($a, $b){
  return $b["voites"] - $a["voites"];
}
```

повторюсь: **нужно, чтобы не нарушался порядок... элементы у которых высший рейтинг должны подниматься вверх, а остальные оставить как есть**

вот так:

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM3
                [id] => 3
                [voites] => 4 // высший рейтинг
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM1
                [id] => 1
                [voites] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM2
                [id] => 2
                [voites] => 0
            )
         [3] => Array
            (
                [title] => ITEM4
                [id] => 4
                [voites] => 0
            )
```

Comment: В данном примере и поля `id`, и индексы элементов массива идут по порядку. Так какой из двух порядков самый правильный? :)

Comment: Странно, галочка появилась и пропала. В чём причина?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По сути, имеется две сортировки: по убыванию `voites` и (при их равенстве) - по возрастанию ключа элемента.
Для применения функции `usort()` надо временно запомнить этот ключ внутри элемента.
Например, так:

```
$common = Array(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "title" => ITEM1,
            "id" => 1,
            "voites" => 0
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "title" => ITEM2,
            "id" => 2,
            "voites" => 0
        ),

    "2" => Array
        (
            "title" => ITEM3,
            "id" => 3,
            "voites" => 4 // высший рейтинг
        ),
     "3" => Array
        (
            "title" => ITEM4,
            "id" => 4,
            "voites" => 0
        )
);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["voites"] == $b["voites"]) {
        if (end($a) == end($b)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (end($a) < end($b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

function add_key(&$item, $key){
    array_push($item,$key);
}

function delete_key(&$item, $key){
    array_pop($item);
}

array_walk($common, 'add_key');
usort($common, 'cmp');
array_walk($common, 'delete_key');
var_dump($common);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'title' => string 'ITEM3' (length=5)
      'id' => int 3
      'voites' => int 4
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'title' => string 'ITEM1' (length=5)
      'id' => int 1
      'voites' => int 0
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'title' => string 'ITEM2' (length=5)
      'id' => int 2
      'voites' => int 0
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'title' => string 'ITEM4' (length=5)
      'id' => int 4
      'voites' => int 0
```

Comment: спасибо. а как работает `callback-функция cmp`?

Comment: Она возвращает единичку для элемента с большим voites, а при их равенстве - для элемента с меньшим индексом. Индексы были записаны функцией array_walk в конец внутренних массивов перед вызовом usort() и таким же образом удалены после обращения. Вставьте парочку дампов - и увидите, как это было

Comment: это понятно.. я имею ввиду как работает сама ф-я `cmp`- сравнивает соседние ячейки? и когда возвращает `-1, 1, 0`?

Comment: В другой теме изложено лучше

Answer (score 2):

А что если просто отсортировать по ключам `voites` и `id`?

```
$arr = [
    [
            "title" => 'ITEM1',
            "id" => 1,
            "voites" => 0
        ],

    [
            "title" => 'ITEM2',
            "id" => 2,
            "voites" => 0
        ],

    [
            "title" => 'ITEM3',
            "id" => 3,
            "voites" => 4 // высший рейтинг
        ],
     [
            "title" => 'ITEM4',
            "id" => 4,
            "voites" => 0
        ]
];

usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    if($a['voites'] === $b['voites']) {
        return (int) $a['id'] < (int) $b['id'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return (int) $a['voites'] < (int) $b['voites'] ? 1 : -1;
});
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ITEM3"
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["voites"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ITEM1"
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["voites"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ITEM2"
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["voites"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ITEM4"
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["voites"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```